# Trying to understand this regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex

```
^(\\w|@|\\-| |\\[|\\]|\\.)+$
```

I'm trying to understand what it does exactly but I can't seem to get any result...
I just can't understand the double backslashes everywhere... Isn't double backslash supposed to be used to get a single backslash?

This regex is to validate that a username doesn't use weird characters and stuff.

If someone could explain me the double backslashes thing please. @_@

Additional info: I got this regex in C# using Regex.IsMatch to check if my username string match the regex. It's for an asp website.

Comment: It sounds like that's in a regular string literal.

Comment: The regex is a string yes.

Comment: One backslash is to escape the second one, because you need to pass the backslash through the language string escaping mechanism. So `\\\\ ` in fact matches a single backslash. `\\n` will match an Unix new line.

Comment: Ok so it's a single backslash because it's in a string

Comment: @Danstahr is correct, the extra backslashes are escape characters that are parsed out before the string hits the regex engine. For more info on C# string literals see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Double slash are supposed to be single slash. Double slash are used to escape the slash itself, as slashes are used for other escape characters *in C# String context* e.g. `\n` stands for new line
2. With double slashes sorted out, it becomes `^(\w|@|\-| |\[|\]|\.)+$`
3. Break down this regex, as `|` means OR, and `\w|@|\-| |\[|\]|\.` would mean `\w` or `@` or `\-` or space or `\[` or `\]` or `\.`. That is, any alphanumeric character, `@`, `-`, space, `[`, `]` and `.` characters. Note that this slash is regex escape, to escape `-`, `[`, `]` and `.` characters as they all have special meanings *in regex context*
4. And, `+` means the previous token (i.e. `\w|@|\-| |\[|\]|\.`) repeated one or more times
5. So, the entire thing means one or more of any combination of alphanumeric character, `@`, `-`, space, `[`, `]` and `.` characters.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. :) I didn't knew for the + that's good to know!

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that it's simply escaping the `\` since backslash is the escape character in c#.

```
string pattern = "^(\\w|@|\\-| |\\[|\\]|\\.)+$";
```

Can be rewritten using a verbatim string as

```
string pattern = @"^(\w|@|\-| |\[|\]|\.)+$";
```

Now it's a bit easier to understand what's going on. It will match any word character, at-sign, hyphen, space, square bracket or period, repeated one or more times. The `^` and `$` match the begging and end of the string, respectively, so only those characters are allowed.

Therefore this pattern is equivalent to:

```
string pattern = @"^([\w@ \[\].-])+$";
```

Comment: Ok so if I understand right, the regex would means : any character, digit or underscore or @ or - or whitespace or [ or ] or .?

Comment: @snaplemouton a space specifically, not any whitespace (that's what `\s` does).

Answer (score 2):

There are online tools to analyze regexes.  Once such is at [http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws](http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws?regex=%5E%28%5Cw%7C@%7C%5C-%7C%20%7C%5C%5B%7C%5C%5D%7C%5C.%29%20%24&env=env_java)

where it reports

```
Sequence: match all of the followings in order
    BeginOfLine
    Repeat
        CapturingGroup
            GroupNumber:1
            OR: match either of the followings
                WordCharacter
                @
                -
                [
                ]
                .
            one or more times
    EndOfLine
```

As others have noted, the double backslashes just escape a backslash so you can embed the regex in a string.  For example, "\\w" will be interpreted as "\w" by the parser.

Answer (score 1):

^ means beginning of the line.

the parentheses is use for grouping

\w is a word character

| means OR

@ match the @ character

\- match the hyphen character

[ and ] matches the squares brackets

\. match a period

+ means one or more

$ the end of line.

So the regex is use to match a string which contains only word characters or an @ or an hyphen or a space or squares brackets or a dot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what it means:

```
^(\\w|@|\\-| |\\[|\\]|\\.)+$
```

`^` - Means the regex starts at the beginning of the string. The match shouldn't start in the middle of the string.

Here's the individual things in the parentheses:

`\\w` - Indicates a "word" character. Normally, this is shown as `\w`, but this is being escaped.

`@` - Indicates an @ symbol is allowed

`\\-` - Indicates a `-` is allowed. This is escaped since the dash can have other meanings in regex. Since it's not in a character class, I don't believe this is technically needed.

- A space is allowed

`\\[` and `\\]` - [ and ]  are allowed.

`\\.` - A period is a valid character. Escaped because periods have special meanings in regex.

Now all of those characters have `|` as delimiters in the parentheses - this means OR. So any of those characters are valid.

The `+` at the end means one or more characters as described in parentheses are valid. The `$` means the end of the regex must match the end of the string.

Note that the double slashes aren't necessary if you just prefix the string like this:

`@"\w"` is the same as `"\\w"`